# How long could a world like the Moon survive with an Earth mass black hole in the center?

Tags: black-hole, gravity

I asked that question at the worldbuilding stack exchange.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/202273/how-long-could-a-planet-or-moon-survive-if-it-had-an-earth-mass-black-hole-withi

Obviously if a small world had a primordial black hole with a greater mass inside, it would have a higher surface gravity and escape velocity than a world of that size made out of even the densest known materials.  Thus the possibility of a fictional habitable world much smaller than otherwise would be the case.

The answers to this question [What would happen if a small black hole fell into a star?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/55461/what-would-happen-if-a-small-black-hole-fell-into-a-star) indicate that I might get a good answer here.

Comment: The surface gravity is ~133.7 m/s^2 (~13.63 *g*). That's not habitable by humans. For 1 *g* gravity you need a BH of Schwarzschild radius 0.54963 mm, just under 0.062 Earth masses. That gives an escape speed of ~52% that of Earth.