# What would happen if a low-mass primordial black hole was captured by a brown dwarf or planet mass object?

Tags: black-hole, planet, brown-dwarf

Prompted by a recent [PBS SpaceTime video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6kJaMf3Lgo)

The video in question discusses what would happen if a low-mass (asteroid-mass) primordial black hole were captured in the core of a Sun-like star (a so-called "Hawking star"), and how it would influence the evolution and characteristics of the star. While the effects might not be particularly obvious for younger G-class stars, it feels intuitively likely that the lower the mass of the star, the greater the proprotional effect would be. In the extreme, a brown dwarf or planet-mass object seems likely to be altered dramatically by the presence of such a PBH. What might those effects be on a "Hawking brown dwarf" or "Hawking planet"?

Comment: Wouldn't it form a very short-lived miniature quasar?

Comment: What do you mean by captured?

Comment: A recent related question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/55461/16685

Comment: @bandybabboon Such black holes have a Schwarzschild radius of under a micron, so the rate that they absorb matter is quite small.

Comment: @ProfRob captured in this context means the black hole is in the core of the brown dwarf/planet.